# Distribution of ages with exponentially distributed resets?

Tags: renewal-processes

Suppose there is a population of trees, and in each period, each tree faces a probability $p$ of getting cut down.
If a tree is cut down, its height is reset to zero (it doesn't die, this is merely a setback for it); if a tree is not cut down, then its height increases by $1$ unit.
Namely, if $h_{t}$ is the height of some tree, then
$$
h_{t+1} = \begin{cases}
h_{t}+1 & \textrm{with probability } 1-p; \\
0 & \textrm{with probability } p.
\end{cases}
$$
What I am looking for is the stationary probability distribution $f(h)$ (for the forest as a whole); I initially thought this would be some trivial extension of the geometric/exponential distribution (ideally I would find a result for continuous time), maybe using convolution? but now I am less sure.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782358/expected-duration-of-completing-a-task-experiencing-exponential-distributed-fail?newreg=5c19b0c006e848298517f086776342d2) question, but it doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for.
I've also started reading William Feller's *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*, so perhaps that will help.

Any suggestions/leads would be appreciated; part of the difficulty has just been figuring out the relevant terms to search for…

Comment: Are trees cut down independently of one another?  I'm confused by what you mean by "for the forest as a whole".

Comment: @saulspatz Yes---each tree faces a constant probability of having its height reset to zero, irrespective of whatever happens to any other tree. Eventually you get a forest with trees of all different heights, and I was trying to figure out what that distribution would be.